# Unique Values in Combobox, Leveraging Max Date from Another Range

Tags: excel, combobox, max, unique, vba

I'm trying to teach myself VBA (primarily in Excel 2010) and I'm stuck on some code.  I've leveraged sites such as Mr. Excel, Excel is Fun, and just about everywhere else that Google takes me, but I'm not having luck finding guidance that makes sense to me.

Challenge:  I have a userform that has a combobox reading a range.  The issue is, the sheet that the range exists on can have multiple duplicate values, but I only want to see unique values.  To make it more challenging (to me), when the User selects a value in the combobox, I want that data set to flow back to the form.

I've managed to get data back on the form, but I'm having difficulty getting the MAX "Entered Date" record.  So, if there are 5 instances of the name "Tom", with "Entered Dates" of 5/1/17, 6/1/17, 7/1/17, 8/17/17, 12/1/17; I want to see the record from 12/1/17.

It appears that I need to do something with a collection to get the unique value in the combobox, but I'm not understanding how it works.  I also have no clue how to tie it all to the MAX "Entered Date".  Here's the code that I have so far:

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Measurements")

LastRow = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws1.Range("B" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Updated
ws1.Range("C" & LastRow) = Me.txt_First
ws1.Range("D" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Last
ws1.Range("E" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Suffix
ws1.Range("F" & LastRow) = Me.cobo_Name
ws1.Range("G" & LastRow) = Me.txt_EntryType
ws1.Range("H" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Height
ws1.Range("I" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Weight
ws1.Range("J" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Chest
ws1.Range("K" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Hips
ws1.Range("L" & LastRow) = Me.txt_Waist
ws1.Range("M" & LastRow) = Me.txt_BicepL
ws1.Range("N" & LastRow) = Me.txt_BicepR
ws1.Range("O" & LastRow) = Me.txt_ThighL
ws1.Range("P" & LastRow) = Me.txt_ThighR
ws1.Range("Q" & LastRow) = Me.txt_CalfL
ws1.Range("R" & LastRow) = Me.txt_CalfR


End Sub
Private Sub cobo_Name_DropButtonClick()

Dim i As Long
Dim coll As Collection
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Measurements")

LastRow = Sheets("Client Measurements").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "F").Value = (Me.cobo_Name) Or _
Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "F").Value = Val(Me.cobo_Name) Then
    Me.txt_First = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "C").Value
    Me.txt_Last = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "D").Value
    Me.txt_Suffix = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "E").Value
    Me.txt_Height = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "H").Value
    Me.txt_Weight = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "I").Value
    Me.txt_Chest = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "J").Value
    Me.txt_Hips = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "K").Value
    Me.txt_Waist = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "L").Value
    Me.txt_BicepL = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "M").Value
    Me.txt_BicepR = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "N").Value
    Me.txt_ThighL = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "O").Value
    Me.txt_ThighR = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "P").Value
    Me.txt_CalfL = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "Q").Value
    Me.txt_CalfR = Sheets("Client Measurements").Cells(i, "R").Value


End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim cCMName As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Measurements")

For Each cCMName In ws1.Range("CMName")
    With Me.cobo_Name
        .AddItem cCMName.Value
    End With
Next cCMName

txt_EntryType = "Check In"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question, but an illustration of how you might go about it. This uses a Dictionary. You add a key and item pair and update the item if the new value in B is higher than the existing item.

```
Sub x()

Dim vData, r As Long

vData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        If vData(r, 2) > .Item(vData(r, 1)) Then
            .Item(vData(r, 1)) = vData(r, 2)
        End If
    Next r
    Range("D1").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    Range("E1").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.items)
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Forgive me, but I'm unclear on some of it though.

vData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value - The Name is the first range I'm interrogating.  I haven't used CurrentRegion.Value to do anything yet, so I'm unclear how that factors in.

Also, the UBound(vData,1) snippet...What is the UBound doing?  I assume that the 1 is the column count?

Finally, I don't see where I'm declaring the EnteredDate as a Range.  Is that what the vData(r,2) is doing?

Apologies for what probably seem like silly questions.

Comment: There's plenty of help online for Scripting Dictionaries, e.g. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ It is probably better than a Collection. If you have specific queries post back.

Comment: Ok, didn't see your questions. I'll come back to later if nobody else has provided another answer in the meantime.

Comment: Perhaps the example is not that useful. It demonstrates how to select the name and max date only - this is added to a dictionary (rather than a collection) and you can then loop through it to add items to the combobox. vData is just turning the range into an array for quicker processing so vData(r,1) is in effect the column A entries (name) and vData(r,2) is column B (date). The date is only added to the dictionary if it is greater than the existing item. If you want to pursue this approach, there are examples online of these various things, give it a try and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be posting a new question in a separate thread, but realized that I never marked this one as answered.  Here is the code that solved my problem:

```
Set coboDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With coboDict
For Each cStatsClientID In ws1.Range("StatsClientID")
    If Not .exists(cStatsClientID.Value) Then
        .Add cStatsClientID.Value, cStatsClientID.Row
    Else
        If CLng(cStatsClientID.Offset(, -2).Value) > CLng(ws1.Range("B" & .Item(cStatsClientID.Value))) Then
        .Item(cStatsClientID.Value) = cStatsClientID.Row
        End If
    End If
Next cStatsClientID
Me.cobo_ClientID.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```